# How to apply a signer from `ethjs-provider-signer` to `eth-provider` instance?

Tags: metamask, ethereumjs, web3-providers

To mimic Metamask plugin behavior (for Dapp testing purposes) I packed a simple provider [chimera-provider](https://github.com/gubnota/chimera-provider) which is just a modified `ethereum-provider` from `@metamask/providers` package (only HTTP version, not WS). The goal is to mimic write request to the blockchain. Although:

A. you can import your `${my_public_account}` from private key:

```js
window.web3.eth.accounts.wallet.clear()
window.web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(
    window.web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(
        `${PRIVATE_KEY}`
    )
)
```

B. You can sign and send a transaction:

```js
token.methods
.approve(ethSwap.address, `${my_public_account}`)
.send({ from: `${my_public_account}`})
.once('sending', function(sending){ console.log({sending}) })
.once('sent', function(sent){ console.log({sent}) })
.once('transactionHash', function(transactionHash){ console.log({transactionHash}) })
.once('receipt', function(receipt){ console.log({receipt}) })
.on('confirmation', function(confNumber, receipt, latestBlockHash){ console.log({confirmation:'confirmation',confNumber,receipt,latestBlockHash}) })
.on('error', function(error){ console.log({error}) })
.then(function(receipt){
  console.log({receipt})
    // will be fired once the receipt is mined
});
```

C. Here you'll catch an error:

```
{error: {message: "The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available", code: -32601}}
```

And **eth_sendTransaction** implementation inside `ethereum-provider` is empty, it returns `false`. Thus, you need somehow to import it.
Luckily, there is a package `ethjs-provider-signer` which you can use to sign each transaction and send it as raw (as it is signed already). But how to apply this piece of code from the package description to already initialized `ethereum` / `web3` instance?

```js
const SignerProvider = require('ethjs-provider-signer');
const sign = require('ethjs-signer').sign;
const Eth = require('ethjs-query');
const provider = new SignerProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io', {
  signTransaction: (rawTx, cb) => cb(null, sign(rawTx, '0x...privateKey...')),
  accounts: (cb) => cb(null, ['0x407d73d8a49eeb85d32cf465507dd71d507100c1']),
});
const eth = new Eth(provider);

eth.sendTransaction({
  from: '0x407d73d8a49eeb85d32cf465507dd71d507100c1',
  gas: 300000,
  data: '0x...',
}, cb);

// results null 0x... (transaction hash)
```

Here is a question:

## Does anybody know how?